# Convert XML to HTML

Tags: html, xml, wordpress

How to convert this in HTML or to import in Wordpress?

```
<ETATS>
    <SECTEUR nom="Bernex" ent_id="129" sct_id="1">
        <REMONTEE nom="Le Pré Richard" etat="HP" type="TSD" ent_id="129" sct_id="1" pag_id="2" prl_id="7" msg="" attente="0" longueur="1223" duree="0" debit="0" alt_depart="0" alt_arrivee="0" denivele="0" vitesse="" capacite="" acces_pietons_hiver="" acces_pietons_ete="" acces_vtt_ete="" nocturne="" aurore="" heuredeb="00:00" heurefin="23:59" heuredebmod="00:00" heurefinmod="23:59" heuredesc="23:59" heuredescmod="23:59">
            <PLAGES>
                <PLAGE ent_id="129" prd_id="1" pgh_id="" heuredeb="" heurefin=""/>
            </PLAGES>
        </REMONTEE>
        <REMONTEE nom="Maupas" etat="HP" type="TLC" ent_id="129" sct_id="1" pag_id="2" prl_id="6" msg="" attente="0" longueur="61" duree="0" debit="0" alt_depart="0" alt_arrivee="0" denivele="0" vitesse="" capacite="" acces_pietons_hiver="" acces_pietons_ete="" acces_vtt_ete="" nocturne="" aurore="" heuredeb="00:00" heurefin="23:59" heuredebmod="00:00" heurefinmod="23:59" heuredesc="23:59" heuredescmod="23:59">
            <PLAGES>
                <PLAGE ent_id="129" prd_id="1" pgh_id="" heuredeb="" heurefin=""/>
            </PLAGES>
        </REMONTEE>
        <PISTE nom="Le Petit Combet" etat="HP" type="A" ent_id="129" sct_id="1" pag_id="1" prl_id="6" msg="" niveau="R" entretien_txt="" entretien_num="0" longueur="0" surface="0" alt_depart="0" alt_arrivee="0" denivele="0" pistequaliteneige="100" enneigeurs="" neige_garantie="" nocturne="" aurore="" heuredeb="00:00" heurefin="23:59" heuredebmod="00:00" heurefinmod="23:59" heuredesc="23:59" heuredescmod="23:59">
            <PLAGES>
                <PLAGE ent_id="129" prd_id="1" pgh_id="" heuredeb="" heurefin=""/>
            </PLAGES>
        </PISTE>
        <PISTE nom="Descente aux Esserts" etat="HP" type="SN" ent_id="129" sct_id="1" pag_id="7" prl_id="2" msg="" niveau="" entretien_txt="" entretien_num="0" longueur="0" surface="0" alt_depart="0" alt_arrivee="0" denivele="0" pistequaliteneige="100" enneigeurs="" neige_garantie="" nocturne="" aurore="" heuredeb="00:00" heurefin="23:59" heuredebmod="00:00" heurefinmod="23:59" heuredesc="23:59" heuredescmod="23:59">
            <PLAGES>
                <PLAGE ent_id="129" prd_id="1" pgh_id="" heuredeb="" heurefin=""/>
            </PLAGES>
        </PISTE>
    </SECTEUR>
</ETATS>undefined</STATION>undefined</SKIPLAN>
```

i need to get data from xml and add in wordpress or as html 
thanks.

Comment: Please write your question and title in a structured fashion to make it easier to help you. You can preview how your question is going to be displayed, while writing it and you can also always edit your question to make it more understandable.

Comment: Here are instructions on [how to write a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: put your code which you try to run with it.